# How to set JQGrid value globally fro all application?

Tags: jquery, jqgrid

I have multiple JQGrids in my application. I want to set some attributes of all JQGrid at one place. So that i don't have need to set those attributes on all grids of application.For example, i want to set `loadonce: true` for all JQgrids.
Is there any way to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need just change *default options*, which will be applied for all jqGrids. To set `loadonce: true` for example you should execute the code

```
$.extend(true, $.jgrid.defaults, {
    // new default values for some options
    loadonce: true
});
```

after including `jquery.jqgrid.min.js` (or `jquery.jqgrid.src.js`), but **before** the first grid is created.

Comment: you made my day. Running like a champ.

Comment: @Hiba: You are welcome! I create `myProjectSettings.js` file typically where I set all default settings of jqGrid which I need in the project: `$.jgrid.defaults`, `$.jgrid.edit`, `$.jgrid.view`, `$.jgrid.del`, `$.jgrid.search`, `$.jgrid.nav`. I include the file on **all HTML pages** of the project. Then I just create jqGrids with short number of parameters. In the way I have one place where I maintain all default setting of the grids.

Comment: Yes, i am also going to do same thing. And also i have seen freeJQgrid that you have created. You have strong grip on jqgrid. I really appreciate this.

Comment: @Hiba: [Free jqGrid](https://github.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid) have some additional possibilities, which can simplify setting of default options of **some other methods** of the grid. I described the possibilities in [the wiki article](https://github.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid/wiki/New-style-of-usage-options-of-internal-methods).